# Razor if-statement using c# method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a C# MVC project using Razor for views.

In my _Layout.cshtml file i want to hide menuoptions based on bools in a helper class.

```
@using Project.HelpMethods;

<li id="menuOptionAppleIds">
@Html.ActionLink("A", "A", "Home")
</li>
```

How do i call a statis bool method in HelpMethods and use in as the expression in an if statement around the `<li>` element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@if (Project.HelpMethods.IsOk())
{
    <li id="menuOptionAppleIds">
        @Html.ActionLink("A", "A", "Home")
    </li>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@if(Helper.ShowMenuOption(x))
{
 <li id="menuOptionAppleIds">
  @Html.ActionLink("A", "A", "Home")
 </li>
}
```

You can use if-statements and method calls in razor as in every other C# file. The difference is to ad @symbol before the c# code